# how to disable/hide browser window buttons like minimize maximize using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

here i have attached the image. I want to disable those buttons.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You have no authority over the user's software controls.

Comment: Funny that the first comment on the linked duplicate is the same as the first comment here.